# Passives derived from two-place predicates

Tags: grammar

Take a look at the following examples:

(1) a. Tom gave Mary a cake.
b. A cake was given to Mary.
c. Mary was given a cake.

Is sentence (2c) grammatical?

(2) a. Tom baked Mary a cake.
b. A cake was baked for Mary.
c. Mary was baked a cake.

Comment: It's not wrong but it's clumsy. *Mary was baked* also means she was drunk.

Comment: We don't have that expression in the UK but (2c) IS clumsy. Maybe because it sounds like a nursery rhyme. We'd usually say "They baked Mary a cake."

Comment: Grammatically correct but you should only use it if it is totally irrelevant who baked Mary the cakes. I can think of very few situations where that wouldn’t be relevant or at least add useful context.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - you mean high.  I thought for a minute "baked" might have undergone the same transformation as "stoned," but I think it has only ever had one meaning.

Comment: 2c is clumsy, but it becomes less so if it's part of "Mary was baked a cake by Tom."